# Unable to upload proguard mapping file on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-proguard, firebase-crash-reporting

I am using firebase crash reporting API in my Android app.
Crash reporting is working fine and showing the error on crash reporting dashboard.
But I am not able to upload mapping.txt file on the firebase.
I got mapping file from below location.

`\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt`

The firebase dashboard image is below

[image]

Comment: If you have an unexplained error that persists, contact Firebase support https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I send bug report with details and image and waiting for there reply @DougStevenson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contact firebase support team and they give me some suggestions as bellow.

Please retry using an incognito window, or do the following when uploading proguard mapping file:
– log out of your dashboard
– clear your browser cache
– disable all plugins/extensions/addons
– restart the browser
– log in again

If you are still having issues:

– try to connect using other browser or network

– open your JavaScript console and see if there are errors
– send us your browser/os version
– send a screenshot of errors in JavaScript console if possible

I solved my issue when I try to upload a file from another browser.

Hope this will help anyone who is facing the same problem like me.